# TFS 2017 Add item to 'New Items' on Kanban board

Tags: tfs

I created a new WIT on TFS2017 - 'DevOps PBI'.  It shows in the Work -> New Work Item -> [DevOps PBI] area, but I would like to add it to the '+ New Item' drop down on the board itself [and remove the two other items there].  I tried using the process editor in VS 2019, the board settings itself, but no luck.  I know it is possible because someone added a custom type, how does one do this?

It shows here:

[image]

Want it to show here:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is detailed instruction: [Add a WIT to track it like a requirement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/add-wits-to-backlogs-and-boards?view=azure-devops-2019#add-a-wit-to-track-it-like-a-requirement). General steps:

1. Add to your new work item type definition the service fields: [Add a WIT to track it like a requirement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/add-wits-to-backlogs-and-boards?view=azure-devops-2019#add-a-wit-to-track-it-like-a-requirement) (step 2. Edit the WIT definition to support planning tools)
2. Add your new work item type to the requirements category: [Use categories to group work item types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/use-categories-to-group-work-item-types?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops-2019), [Import and export categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-categories?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops-2019)
3. Check your process to map states of your new work item type to the process meta states: [Add a WIT to track it like a requirement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/add-wits-to-backlogs-and-boards?view=azure-devops-2019#add-a-wit-to-track-it-like-a-requirement) (Step 4. Update or verify ProcessConfiguration definition), [Import and export process configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-process-configuration?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops-2019)

Comment: This is just insane.  I risk breaking many things by doing this - and not knowing the specifics.  Items such as broken documentation (the closing tags on the xml elements when adding fields?) - this is too scary for me to touch.  I can't believe this is the official approach.